# displays the movie titles that have never been rented by the customers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried several times to answer the following question with Oracle 12: write the SQL statement that displays movie titles that were never rented by customers?

Here is the schema I need to follow to answer the question: [here is the schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3rZX.png)

```
SELECT titre 
FROM film INNER JOIN copie ON film.id_film = copie.id_film
          INNER JOIN location ON copie.id_copie = location.id_copie
          INNER JOIN client ON client.id_clt = location.id_client
WHERE id_loc IS NULL;
```

when i made this request, it gave me no result. i strongly believe that there is something missing in my request but i don't know what. Could someone please help me?

Comment: *Hint* : Use Outer Join

Comment: Please, describe what exact part of your code does "that has never been rented"?

Comment: in my WHERE clause with IS NULL

Comment: I was thinking about that too: WHERE NOT EXIST

Comment: Please share the create table statements and some sample data (text, NOT screenshots). That makes it a lot easier to help you. From what you shared, it is impossible for us how to know how a rented movie is stored in the database.
That being said, if you want to capture an event of type that does not exist (you want movies that have _not_ been rented) then "WHERE NOT EXISTS" is the way to go.

Comment: @K3N72 You need to check the definition of join types. `INNER JOIN` (which is also the same as `JOIN`) returns only those rows from both the tables that satisfy join predicate (where the predicate evaluates to `TRUE`)

Answer (score 0):

> write the SQL statement that displays movie titles that were never rented by customers?

I don't see that info in ERD you posted, but - I presume you do know which table stores information about movies being rented. In that case, one option is to use the `MINUS` set operator; something like this:

```
select movie_id from all_movies
minus
select movie_id from movies_being_rented;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework question:

You can `INNER JOIN` the `copie` to `location` on their primary and foreign key relationship and put that into a sub-query.

Then, you can either:

1. Take the `film` table and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` it to that sub-query and then `GROUP BY` the `film`'s primary key and find the films `HAVING` a `COUNT` of zero rows in the joined sub-query and return the `title` (using an aggregation function or adding `title` to the `GROUP BY` clause); or
2. Find, for each `film`, `WHERE` there `NOT EXISTS` a matching row in that sub-query.